# Lubuntu on Raspberry Pi 4(arm64) Display Resolution Setting

Tags: display, ubuntu

My Pi is running Lubuntu 20.04 LTS. It does not fit to full screen to my 1920*1080 monitor. The system is using 1824*984. And this is the only option it provides. Now there are two black strips on both top and bottom of my screen. Can I add customised resolution setting to it?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to know the refresh rate of the monitor for these - I have assumed 60Hz :)

Create a mode line using

```
cvt 1920 1080 60
```

Take a copy of all the data after the 'modeline' text

Find the name of your screen using

```
xrandr
```

I assume it's VGA1 and add a new screen mode

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" xxxx
```

Where xxxx is the numeric data from the cvt output - note quotes around name.

Add the mode to you monitor

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00
```

Note no quotes around the name (nothing like standards)...

Use the mode with the command:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

Again no quotes.

I don not think this is permanent - you many need to add this each time you boot.

If you have a GUI, then look at [ResolutionX](https://github.com/fr3nzy/ResolutionX) on Github as the two python programs will do this for you with a nice GUI **BUT** it does not have any instructions!